Teradata Windows analytical function to select the correct records from partition
I have just 2 columns for partition and on basis of those two columns, need to select the appropriate dates.
Input Data:



strt_dt
end_dt
ID
Amt




2023-09-29
2023-10-01
ID1
100


2023-10-02
2023-10-02
ID1
100


2023-10-03
2023-10-03
ID1
100


2023-10-04
2023-10-04
ID1
200


2023-10-05
2023-10-05
ID1
100



Expected Output:



strt_dt
end_dt
ID
Amt




2023-09-29
2023-10-03
ID1
100


2023-10-04
2023-10-04
ID1
200


2023-10-05
2023-10-05
ID1
100



Actual Output:



strt_dt
end_dt
ID
Amt




2023-09-29
2023-10-05
ID1
100


2023-10-04
2023-10-04
ID1
200



I have used min(strt_dt) OVER (PARTITION by id, amt ORDER BY strt_dt) which is the cause of the overlapping results.
Do I need to do anything differently?

Could you add the sql query you tried, in the question?

It can be achieve in 2 ways, I will provide both simple and complex versions.
ROW_NUMBER() will work for the requirement, however your need to use it twice (first without amount and then with amount). The below approach is a simple version,
WITH consecutive_blocks AS (
    SELECT
        strt_dt,
        end_dt,
        ID,
        Amt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY strt_dt) AS rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Amt ORDER BY strt_dt) AS rn2
    FROM 
        table_a
)
SELECT 
    MIN(strt_dt) AS strt_dt,
    MAX(end_dt) AS end_dt,
    ID,
    Amt
FROM 
    consecutive_blocks
GROUP BY 
    ID, Amt, (rn1 - rn2)
ORDER BY 
    strt_dt;


There is an efficient way of achieving the same result, but it will be a more complex one,
WITH flagged_rows AS (
    SELECT
        strt_dt,
        end_dt,
        ID,
        Amt,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(Amt) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY strt_dt) = Amt THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS flag
    FROM 
        table_a
),
grouped_rows AS (
    SELECT 
        strt_dt,
        end_dt,
        ID,
        Amt,
        SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY strt_dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
    FROM 
        flagged_rows
)
SELECT 
    MIN(strt_dt) AS strt_dt,
    MAX(end_dt) AS end_dt,
    ID,
    Amt
FROM 
    grouped_rows
GROUP BY 
    ID, Amt, grp
ORDER BY 
    strt_dt;


I've used the first approach. thank you.

You want to combine contigous rows, Teradata has a nice syntax for it. As it's based on Standard SQL PERIOD logic (start and end are inclusive/exclusive), but your implementation is using inclusive/inclusive begin/end, you need to adjust your end date:
SELECT NORMALIZE -- this does all the magic
  PERIOD(strt_dt, NEXT(end_dt) AS d -- adjust end date to make it inclusive
  ,ID
  ,Amt
FROM mytable;

This returns a Period, if you want to split it back into start/end:
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE
      PERIOD(strt_dt, NEXT(end_dt) AS d
     ,ID
     ,Amt
   FROM mytable
 )
SELECT 
   BEGIN(pd) AS strt_dt
  ,LAST(pd) AS end_dt -- returns the last included date
  ,ID
  ,amt
FROM cte

